# Android DataBinding custom adapter in multiple modules

Tags: android, android-databinding

#### Context

I have 3 modules: `A`, `B`, and `app`. `app` depends on `A`, and `A` depends on `B`.

Custom data binding adapters are in `B`.

```
app -> A -> B
```

All modules have data binding enabled, as well as kapt plugin.

```
plugins {
    kotlin("kapt")
}

android {
    dataBinding.isEnabled = true
}
```

#### Problem

Let's say I have the following binding adpater function:

```
@BindingAdapter("fontWeight")
fun TextView.setFontWeight(family: String)
```

In `app`, I can use it as an extension function, but cannot use it as a custom binding adapter.

```
textView.setFontWeight("bold") // It works

<TextView
  app:fontWeight='@{"bold"}' // It doesn't work
```

What's interesting is that If I make `app` module directly depends on `B`, then the binding adapter works as expected.

```
app -> B
```

What's the problem? Do you have any ideas? Thanks in advance.

#### Update

When I remove this lines of code from `build.gradle.kts` it works properly, but I cannot figure out what's going on.

```
flavorDimensions("dimension")

productFlavors {
    create("dev")
    create("staging")
    create("production")

    forEach { flavor ->
        with(flavor) {
            dimension = "dimension"
            versionCode = generateVersionCode(name)
            versionName = generateVersionName(name)

            if (name != "production") {
                applicationIdSuffix = ".$name"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @JeelVankhede I've tried it. It did not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that I used same package name in `AndroidManifest.xml` for both module A and module B.

```xml
<!-- AndroidManifest.xml in Module A -->
<manifest package="co.riiid.santa.design" />

<!-- AndroidManifest.xml in Module B -->
<manifest package="co.riiid.santa.design" />
```

Changing package name of module B solves the problem.

```
<!-- Append "components" at the end -->
<manifest package="co.riiid.santa.design.components" />
```

I didn't expect that it might cause a problem..

---

I'm not sure why it causes the problem, but here's my guess:

Annotation processing tool `kapt` generates a class `DataBinderMapperImpl` for each module that has enabled data binding. The resulting class is located in the package where one specified in `AndroidManifest.xml`

[image: Package structure for reference]

Hence if there're modules which have the same package name, a conflict occurs.

Answer (score 0):

I think this be difference of `implementation` and `api` in gradle.
When you use `implementation` for A and you can use that modules and when use `api`   your app is depend on A and all its dependencies like B.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I've tried it and it didn't help. I managed to solve the problem, and posted the solution below. 